# Webpack hot reload via gulp, publicPath causing issues

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I can't seem to get the hot reload function to work correctly for me. Whenever I do an update I get the following error messages:

*Get http://localhost:9090/cd0492f7657672ef15e4.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)*
*[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!*
*[HMR] (Probably because of restarting the webpack-dev-server)*

I am pretty sure this is caused by `publicPath: '/js/',` in `gulpfile.js` as when I go to `http://localhost:9090/cd0492f7657672ef15e4.hot-update.json` I get a 404 but when I go to `http://localhost:9090/js/cd0492f7657672ef15e4.hot-update.json` I can find the file.

However `publicPath: '/js/'` is needed for `app.js` so I have no idea how to fix it, any ideas?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './resources/assets/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        publicPath: '/js/',
        filename: "scripts.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
...
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
...
gulp.task('webpack-dev-server', function(callback) {
    // modify some webpack config options
    var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
    myConfig.devtool = 'eval';
    myConfig.debug = true;
    myConfig.plugins = [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ];

    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    new webpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
        hot: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true
        },
        publicPath: '/js/',
        proxy: {
            '*': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    }).listen(9090, 'localhost', function(err) {
        if (err) throw new gulpUtil.PluginError('webpack-dev-server', err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Github issue with a workaround that I used that might be helpful: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/252